# How to use a SVG React component as background?

Tags: reactjs

I have SVG files written in Function Components.

```
import React from "react";

const MySVGBackground= (props) => {
  return (
    <svg> some svg here</svg>
  );
};

export default MySVGBackground;
```

I need to render this as a background:

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${MySVGBackground})` }}> </div>
```

but it's not working.

I can't purely import the SVG directly, because it gives me an error of Unexpected Token. So I have to wrap the SVG into the FC and export it.

Here is the sample code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-background-issue-9wt4x?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Does your svg need to be dynamic? If so, are you intending to pass props to it?

Comment: static, not passing any props to it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-background-issue-ut933

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import BackgroundSVG from "./backgroundSVG";
// import this to render static markup
import { renderToStaticMarkup } from 'react-dom/server';

export default function App() {
  // convert component to string useable in data-uri
  const svgString = encodeURIComponent(renderToStaticMarkup(<BackgroundSVG />));

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url("data:image/svg+xml,${svgString}")`
        }}
      >
        Svg background
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The data: **image/svg+xml;utf8** part tells the browser that raw image data is following.

More information can be found here:
https://css-tricks.com/lodge/svg/09-svg-data-uris/
https://gist.github.com/iansinnott/2e8fe9d9e4c6c7c55793d38f81c999a3

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-background-issue-9wt4x?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Please check my updated answer. If this what you want then I would be happy if you accept the answer.